# wand - text wrapping - based on the image file size

Tags: python, python-3.x, wand, magickwand

Hi am trying to write text over an image. But the text overflows. Is there any way to wrap such textual content to fit inside the image?

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color

with Image(filename='/home/path/image.jpg').clone() as img:
    print('width =', img.width)
    print('height =', img.height)
    quote = input('quote:')
    with Drawing() as draw:
        draw.font = 'wandtests/assets/League_Gothic.otf'
        draw.fill_color=Color('red')
        draw.text_alignment= 'center'
        img.font_size=50
        draw.text(int(img.width/2),int(img.height/2), quote)
        print(draw.get_font_metrics(img,quote))
        draw(img)
        print('text drawn')
    img.save(filename='/home/path/image01.jpg')
```

input given is:

```
"Success makes so many people hate you. I wish it wasn't that way. It would be wonderful to enjoy success without seeing envy in the eyes of those around you."
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmhPh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution is to split the string in two pieces:

```
draw.text(int(img.width/3),int(img.height/3), quote[0:len(quote)//2])
draw.text(int(2 * img.width/3),int(2 * img.height/3), quote[len(quote)//2:-1])
```

Splitting in 3 or more may be required if the text is still to long.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of drawing text, use the [`caption`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.2/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.caption) method that `Image` inherits from `BaseImage`.